# Do a search using filter but ignoring punctuations

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

I wrote a search filter for an ionic project below. It works fine but for the fact that it does not ignore punctuations.

So if the item i am searching for an item that has a comma and I miss the comma I won't find it. Is there a way for me to tell the filter to ignore commas and maybe even other punctuations as well?

See a few snippets of my example below:

```
<input class="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.searchQuery">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item  collection-repeat="hymn in hymns | filter: data.searchQuery">
    <h2><b>{{hymn.number}}. </b>{{hymn.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Javascript

```
var hymns = [
{
    "body": "I've written a body, it has punctuation too;\n",
    "number": 1,
    "title": "This Title, has a comma! and puctuations"
}, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could call a function to filter the items:

   ```
   <ion-item collection-repeat="hymn in hymns | filter: myCustomFilter">
       <h2><b>{{hymn.number}}. </b>{{hymn.title}}</h2>
       <p>{{hymn.body}}
   </ion-item>
   ```

   Then define it in the controller:

   ```
   $scope.myCustomFilter = function(hymn) {
       var searchTerm = $scope.data.searchQuery || '';
       searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase()

       var hymnTitle = hymn.title.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
       var hymnBody = hymn.body.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();    

       return hymnTitle.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1|| hymnBody.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
   }
   ```

   [Codepen example using function](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/eNVaBZ?editors=101)
2. You could also create a custom Angular filter:

   ```
   <ion-item collection-repeat="hymn in hymns | filterPunctuation: data.searchQuery">
       <h2><b>{{hymn.number}}. </b>{{hymn.title}}</h2>
       <p>{{hymn.body}}
   </ion-item>
   ```

   Then define the filter like this:

   ```
   .filter('filterPunctuation', function() {
     return function(items, searchTerm) {
       if (!searchTerm || '' === searchTerm) {
         return items;
       }

       searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();

       return items.filter(function(element, index, array) {
         var title = element.title.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
         var body = element.body.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
         return title.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || body.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
       });
     }
   })
   ```

   [Codepen example using filter](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/XbZwdK?editors=101)

Both ways I am using a regular expression to filter out all of the punctuation from the search term and the hymn property, and then I am converting both of them to lower case so the user doesn't have to type it exactly as it is. There are many different ways you can do this. Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution is unfortunately limited to Chrome and Firefox because it uses the includes function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes so it unfortunately wont work for my ionic-frameowork app, I would appreciate it if you could suggest an alternative method

Comment: Good point @frazras. I have updated my answer & Codepen examples to use `indexOf` instead of `includes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<input class="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.$">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item  collection-repeat="hymn in hymns | filter: data">
    <h2><b>{{hymn.number}}. </b>{{hymn.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/I9XEk7ebBeWbzQtwdMPv?p=preview

I hope this will help you

Comment: How does this answer my question about ignoring punctuations?

Comment: you can see in plunker there is an example of ANY in which value consists '-' and it is searchable

Comment: but what I meant was I wanted to be able to search for a number without including the hyphen eg: 5551234 instead of 555-1234