# AngularJs search filter ignore punctuation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with some data. It has name, code, phone, etc.. And this table can have dynamic fields, based on the client option.

I could found a code to make this search ignore the punction, but it has some limitations. On the `.filter` i need to specify which field I'm going to search, so, because my table is dynamic i don't know what field is being displayed.

This is the [link i got the answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200448/do-a-search-using-filter-but-ignoring-punctuations).

And this is the code I'm using:

***app.js***

```
.filter('filterMaster', function() {
    return function(items, searchTerm) {
        if (!searchTerm || '' === searchTerm) {
            return items;
        }
        searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
        return items.filter(function(element, index, array) {
            var title = element.cod_order.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();
            return title.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
        });
    }
})
```

I also tried using this code, which i got [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164671/angularjs-search-and-ignore-spanish-characters):

***app.js***

```
$scope.ignoreAccents = function(item) {
    if (!$scope.searchField)
        return true;
    var text = removeAccents(item.cod_order.toLowerCase())
    var search = removeAccents($scope.searchField.toLowerCase());
    return text.indexOf(search) > -1;
};
function removeAccents(value) {
    return value
    .replace(/á/g, 'a')
    .replace(/é/g, 'e')
    .replace(/í/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ó/g, 'o')
    .replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "")
    .replace(/ú/g, 'u');
};
```

But again, if i don't specify the `cod_order`, or other field I want to search, it doesn't work. And if i set the field i want to search, than i can't search in anyother field on the table.

The main problem with this, is because i can't search any other field if it's not being set inside this filter.

Is there a way to optimize it so it work doesn't matter what field the table has? And without the need to specify the field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
.filter('filterMaster', function () {
return function (items, searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm === '') return items;
    var filtered = [];
    var str = searchTerm.replace(/\./g, '');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var itemTmp = items[i];
        var found = false;
        $.each(itemTmp, function (i, n) {
            if(i =='$$hashKey' || found )
                return;
            var replaced = n.toString().replace(/\./g, '');
            if (replaced.indexOf(str) >= 0) 
            {
                filtered.push(itemTmp);
                found = true;
            }
        });
    }
    return filtered;
};
```

});

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryosh/vugsq2m5/4/) working code.

Comment: i was traying to use your code but i'm with some errors. When i type in my input, nothing happens. I tried to log the `searchTerm` but it's always blank. And if i dont set the `$scope.myinputsearch` inside my controler, i have this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` in this part here: `var str = searchTerm.replace(/\./g, '');` any ideas?

Comment: I just noticed you are using Jquery. Is there a way to keep it pure AngularJs? Because I'm not using Jquery in my app.

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ryosh/vugsq2m5/5/) code update with pure javascript. Try initialize $scope.myinputsearch = ''; or check in code if it is undefined. Something like *if(!myinputsearch) return items;

Comment: Ok, now it's working. There were a few things i changed. Since I'm getting data from database, sometimes it has a null field, so i made a change to convert it to just blank field. Also, since I'm dealing with big data, it has some delay to process it. Do you know how to optmize this code to work better with a lot of data? Or just hide with css instead of show/hide in each type on the search? This is the fiddle I'm using with those changes: https://jsfiddle.net/vugsq2m5/6/